# Create Subdomain on BigRock with Godaddy hosting

Tags: dns, subdomain, web-hosting, nameservers

I have a domain on BigRock and hosting on GoDaddy. I am also using CloudFlare in between. Now I need to add a subdomain on BigRock which should also point to a subdomain on GoDaddy.

I have created a Subdomain on GoDaddy hosting successfully. However actions might also be needed on BigRock and Cloudflare.

I tried to add a CName record on Bigrock looking at some tutorials online. But it said HostName and Value cannot be same. There's very small help available on adding subdomain on BigRock where as for GoDaddy is was easy.

I need the steps needed to complete what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not on Godaddy panel. Since your domain point to Cloudflare name server, you must add your A record on Cloudflare panel. Please test.